Google Play Install Referrer Library not showing correct utm params
I have integrated Google Play Install Referrer API and created a campaign link using my app package name:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.humbleapp&referrer=utm_source%3Djampp%26utm_medium%3DBanner%26utm_term%3DPuma%2520Shues%26utm_content%3Dssadad%26utm_campaign%3Dasdsa%26anid%3Djampp%26aclid%3D{hash}
Then follow the below steps to test:
Start Google Play on the device using the campaign link, for example,

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.humbleapp&referrer=utm_source%3Djampp%26utm_medium%3DBanner%26utm_term%3DPuma%2520Shues%26utm_content%3Dssadad%26utm_campaign%3Dasdsa%26anid%3Djampp%26aclid%3D{hash}

DIDN'T TAP ON INSTALL BUTTON

Install test build using adb install -r app-debug.apk


In the logs I am getting:
referrerUrl: utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic
even though i have provided utm_source as jampp
Could someone please help with what recently has changed? This was working until last month
